# Python Multiprocessing: Each Process returns list

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a program in python which reads from 4 different files, changes the data and writes it to another file.

Currently I am attempting to read and change the data with 4 different processes to speed up the runtime.

I have already tried to use manager.list, but this makes the script slower than sequential.

Is it possible to share a List between processes or to make each process return a list and extend a list in the main process with those lists?

Thanks

The code looks like this (currently myLists stays empty, so nothing is written to the output.csv):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import queue
import time 

myLists=[[],[],[],[]]
myProcesses = []


def readAndList(filename,myList):
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        content = file.read().split(":")
        file.close()
        j=1
        filmid=content[0]
        while j<len(content):
            for entry in content[j].split("\n"):
                if len(entry)>10:
                    print(entry)
                    myList.append(filmid+","+entry+"\n")
                else:
                    if len(entry)>0:
                        filmid=entry
            j+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start=time.time()
    endList=[]
    i=1
    for loopList in myLists:
        myProcesses.append(Process(target=readAndList,args=("combined_data_"+str(i)+".txt",loopList)))
        i+=1
    for process in myProcesses:
        process.start()
    for process in myProcesses:
        process.join()

    k=0
    while k<4:
        endList.extend(myLists[k])
        k+=1

    with open("output.csv","w") as outputFile:
            outputFile.write(''.join(endList))
            outputFile.flush()
            outputFile.close()  

    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a modern way.

As an example..

Assuming that we have several files that store numbers, like

```
1
2
3
4
```

and so on.

This example greps them from the file and combines into the list of lists, so you can merge them as you want. I use python 3.7.2, it should work in 3.7 as well, but I'm not sure.

**Code**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from asyncio import ensure_future, gather, run


async def read(file_list):
    tasks = list()
    result = None

    for file in file_list:
        task = ensure_future(read_one(file))
        tasks.append(task)

        result = await gather(*tasks)

    return result


async def read_one(file):

    result = list()
    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            result.append(int(line[:-1]))

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    res = run(read(files))

    print(res)
```

**Output**

> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]

You can find this source code [here](https://github.com/caa06d9c/Examples/blob/master/Python/basic/asyncio/read_files_in_parallel/run.py)

I think this approach is much faster and easier to read. This example can be extended to grepping data from WEB, you can read the info about it [here](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2017/06/12/making-100-million-requests-with-python-aiohttp/)

Asyncio and aiohttp are really great tools. I recommend trying them.

Comment: Thank you! This works very well. By using your example I managed to reduce the runtime by about 15 Seconds. Is there anything else I could do to improve on that?

Comment: I don't know actually. I assume that there is a lot of ways improving file reading and other logic, like working with lists and so on. But i don't think that it will reduce time a lot. Most performance problems in python related to GIL, so asyncio is best of all to resolve multiprocessing problems related to it.  But if u will find something else, please, report here) Anyway, try to remove semaphore block, read_bounded. It will help a little bit.